# Adding an identity field using code first Entity Framework

Tags: code-first, auto-increment

Here is a model class `Employee` that I use in my MVC project.

```java
public class Employee
{
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int SkillID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Employee Skill")]
        public Skill EmployeeSkill { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Skill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see, I have added the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to the `EmployeeID` property. But still, when I try to insert without specifying the `EmployeeID`, as an input value, I get the following error...

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployeeID', table 'MVCTheRightWayContext-20141028005000.dbo.Employees'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 6):

You have to `Add [Key]` Annotation:

```java
public class Employee
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int SkillID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Employee Skill")]
    public Skill EmployeeSkill { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Skill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please comment on this answer if there is a 'smarter' way to do this.

I found that I could not apply the two annotations above (Key and DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) to an existing field that already exists.

First, I needed drop the table in SQL by deleting the Entity Model and then have Entity Framework recreate table in SQL for my field to be marked as the PK and also have the Identity Specification set.

Hope this saves someone a couple hours of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your code Your Problem will be solved

```java
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
        {                       
            entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeID )
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
             entity.HasKey(x => x.EmployeeID );
        
        });
}
```